# Add html content to a page in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay

Im new to Liferay . I have downloaded the Liferay Tomcat bundle v5.2.3 Community Edition from the Liferay website. I am able to run it successfully.
I am now trying to create an intranet portal for our company using Liferay . I created an Organization in Liferay and added some pages and child pages to it.
How to add content to a page ?. I mean, i would like to add some text and images etc to the home page and other pages on the portal. I tried the Web Content Display portlet, but it always appears minimized and i have to maximise it by clicking on the maximize button. And also the option to minimize/maximize the portlet is available only when im logged in.
Is there any other way to add HTML content to a page, to make it look like a normal html page which anybody can view when they visit the portal ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

Web Content Display is indeed the easiest choice. You probably just made a mistake when using it.

- Add the web content display portet
- Click on "add web content" icon at the bottom-left of the portlet
- You get a rich text editor, but you can also toggle to HTML view
- When you're done click on "Save and approve".

Liferay CMS is built on the concept of template, structure and article.

- structure: the element to be rendered, e.g. one text area + one image
- template: the rendering of the structure, e.g. image in top-left + text around the image
- article: the actual data that corresponds to a structure

But you should be able to edit your first Web Content Display without having an structure nor template. But I suggest you to have a look at them once your are used to the portal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ewernli. Its extremely clear and helpful :). But my only problem is that the web content display portlet appears minimized. Do i have to use the structure/template/article format to make it appear maximized always ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly what you mean by "minimized". Do you see the text "Select existing web content or add some web content to be displayed in this portlet" when you add a web content display portlet? Do you see the 3 buttons at top-right of the portlet or does it display "Return to full page"?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have added the web content portlet and then added content, you need to configure the layout template you want.  Choose the one column layout to let the portlet take up the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to create a new page of type web content.

1. note the content_id of your web content
2. make sure your web content is approved, published, and viewable (permissions)
3. create your page, entering your content_id into the Web Content ID field

I think when you do it this way, you forsake some of the portlet functionality that Liferay brings you.