# How to create custom page components in Liferay?

Tags: html, custom-component, liferay-7

I'm newest in liferay and I need to create a custom page HTML-component and placed it at my page. How to create it correctly using liferay interface?
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914217/add-html-content-to-a-page-in-liferay

Comment: @SahilDhir thanx a lot :)

Comment: you are welcome :)